# MySQL INNER JOIN error in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have problem with query in this example:

```
 SELECT pm.name,
       pm.pre_id,
       pm.pgs_id,
       pm.link,
       pm.del,
       pm.maz_kaina,
       pm.int_kaina,
       pm.d1_kaina,
       pm.d2_kaina,
       pm.d3_kaina,
       pm.pvm,
       pm.vnt,
       pm.gamintojas,
       pm.akcija,
       pm.akc_kaina
FROM   `prekes_main` AS pm
       INNER JOIN (SELECT charak_pre.pr_id
                   FROM   charak_pre
                   WHERE  charak_pre.cha_id = 206
                          AND charak_pre.reiksme = 'Parfumuotas vanduo'
                          AND charak_pre.pr_id = pm.pre_id) AS reikiamos_pre0
               ON reikiamos_pre0.pr_id = pm.pre_id
WHERE  pm.pgs_id = '2431'
ORDER  BY pm.del DESC,
          int_kaina ASC
LIMIT  0, 18
```

I have problem in `INNER JOIN` when I try execute this. This is error which I got:

```
SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'pm.pr_id' in WHERE clause.
```

Location where the error occurs is: `and charak_pre.pr_id = pm.pr_id`. With this I want to select row from charak_pre table witch equals prekes_main row by keys charak_pre.pr_id and prekes_main.pre_id.

Comment: in the SELECT in the parathesis you have only FROM charak_pre. pm is not defined anywhere, that's why the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it without the subquery, seems like a inefficient thing to do, but I haven't tested it. Do a normal join instead:

```
SELECT  pm.name, 
        pm.pre_id, 
        pm.pgs_id, 
        pm.link, 
        pm.del, 
        pm.maz_kaina, 
        pm.int_kaina, 
        pm.d1_kaina, 
        pm.d2_kaina, 
        pm.d3_kaina, 
        pm.pvm, 
        pm.vnt, 
        pm.gamintojas, 
        pm.akcija, 
        pm.akc_kaina
FROM    `prekes_main` as pm
        INNER JOIN charak_pre charak_pre  as reikiamos_pre0 
            ON reikiamos_pre0.pr_id = pm.pre_id AND charak_pre.cha_id = 206 and 
                    charak_pre.reiksme = 'Parfumuotas vanduo'
WHERE   pm.pgs_id = '2431' 
ORDER   BY pm.del DESC, 
        int_kaina ASC 
LIMIT 0,18
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it without a subquery because you haven't perform any aggregation on the following rows. But instead directly join it with table `charak_pre` and put the other condition on the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT pm.*
FROM    prekes_main as pm
        INNER JOIN charak_pre
           ON charak_pre.pr_id = pm.pre_id
WHERE   pm.pgs_id = '2431' AND 
        charak_pre.cha_id = 206 AND 
        charak_pre.reiksme = 'Parfumuotas vanduo'
ORDER   BY pm.del DESC, int_kaina ASC 
LIMIT   0, 18
```

Comment: than this query `SELECT  charak_pre.pr_id 
            FROM    charak_pre 
            WHERE   charak_pre.cha_id = 206 and 
                    charak_pre.reiksme = 'Parfumuotas vanduo'`, return not one result, it returns about 5000+, so JOIN too slow with this

Comment: Hm no maybe its bad that you don't know the table's structure. `prekes_main` have just one row with `pre_id`, but `charak_pre` have more than one pr_id witch equals pre_id in prekes_main, so that query will return more than one same product row

Comment: did you try to execute the query above? see the `DISTINCT` part?

Comment: oww... sory I dont sow that, yes seems it can work I will try it now :)

Comment: @downvoter, are you striking again? I have many answers which means more opportunity `:)`